# Mingw disable TLS ( thread local storage ) on Windows

Tags: windows, dll, mingw, thread-local-storage

Hello i have a project which i converted to dll, compiled with the mingw-w64-i686-toolchain
Problem is when building exe or dll mingw creates 3 tls callbacks TlsCallback_0,TlsCallback_1,TlsCallback_2 and also some TLS data produced and embed in CRT section. This causes my dll to crash, similar project converted using visual studio works. Is there some switch or any solution to disabl tls generation by mingw compiler?

Comment: converted to dll: do you mean built from source?

Comment: @BrechtSanders yes, i changed entry point to DllMain, made an export, and changed cmakelists accordingly to make dll output file, and it compiled without errors. But this tls stuff breaks everything, i get LoadLibrary Error: "0x7a" using GetLastError

Comment: If you have the source I would recommend building from source with the same.compiler and TLS settings instead of tweaking a DLL that was built in another environment.